# C++: Leaving open option for a pointer to point to one of two types

Tags: c++, pointers

In C++, I have two classes: `Node` and `RootNode`.  I would like to have a member for `Node` that can be a pointer to either `Node` or `RootNode`.  Is there any way I can leave open the option for a pointer to point to one of two different classes without needing to commit to one of them until I set the value of that pointer?

I have seen some answers using `union`; I am not sure these will work, since to use a variable defined using a `union` I will have to know whether it is pointing to a `Node` or `RootNode` so I know which object of `union` to reference (`union_typedef.node` or `union_typedef.rootnode`).  I want to be able to use this pointer without needing to know whether it is pointing to a `Node` or a `RootNode`.

Comment: Could you have a common base class?

Comment: Either make them both derived from the same base class, or use a discriminated union.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to do what you *want to do*, and a way to do what you probably *need to do* (and these two are different things).

To do what you want (set a pointer of one of two types) use `union`:

```
struct MyStruct {
    union {
        Node *nodePtr;
        RootNode *rootPtr;
    }
};
```

Above, you can set either `nodePtr` or `rootPtr`, but the union will take space of a single pointer.

What you probably need, however, is a class inheritance with virtual functions, and a pointer to base class:

```
struct Node {
    virtual void doSomething() {
        cout << "I'm a node" << endl;
    }
};

struct RootNode : public Node {
    virtual void doSomething() {
        cout << "I'm a root" << endl;
    }
};
```

You can make a pointer to `Node`, and assign it a pointer to `Node` or to `RootNode`. No matter what you assign, the call of `doSomething()` will be routed to a correct function:

```
Node *n = new Node();
n->doSomething(); // Prints "I'm a node"
delete n;
n = new RootNode();
n->doSomething(); // Prints "I'm a root"
delete n;
```

> Neither `Node` nor `RootNode` derive from the other.

If the derivation hierarchy is fixed and you cannot change it, you can build wrapper classes for `Node` and `RootNode`, have one wrapper derive from the other (or have them both derive from a common ancestor), and make virtual functions that dispatch to the functions of wrapped objects.

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  Use a Union!

```
union { Node *nodePtr; RootNode *rootNodePtr; } unionNodePtr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `RootNode` derive from `Node`, or vice versa?

If so, then simply declare your member as which type is the "base" type.  For example:

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node *member;
};

class RootNode : public Node
{
};
```

If not, you will have to use a `union` instead:

```
class RootNode
{
};

class Node
{
public:
    union {
        RootNode *root;
        Node *node;
    } member;
};
```

Comment: Neither `Node` nor `RootNode` derive from the other.